# How to achieve Material UI's click effect?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

How can the following click effect be implemented with CSS & JS?

See the transition:

1. Visit http://www.material-ui.com/
2. Open the menu via the hamburger icon
3. Click on "Getting Started"
4. Notice the element's background is transitioned with a radial gradient around the click location

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's many of these on Google if you search for `material design ink ripple`. Here's one such CodePen that I found: [link](http://codepen.io/440design/pen/iEztk)

This effect is outlined by Google in their Material Design spec under [Buttons](https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons.html#).

Comment: I played around with a few tutorials and came up with this: https://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/bmnk7dnp/8/  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.